# Adding an existing web application to Odoo

Tags: odoo

I'm new to Odoo, I have a web application that I would like to interface with Odoo(use within Odoo), is there any solution to use a third-party web application with Odoo? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can do it through REST API and java script/xml to render templates

For more info Refer documentation

**http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/index.html**

**Note : The link provided is for version 10 you can navigate based on the version you are using/going to integrate.**